# O que é esse erro net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR ao fazer upload?

Tags: ajax, upload, google-chrome

Eu estou utilizando o Google Chrome para fazer uns testes numa aplicação que estou dando manutenção. Especificamente estou utilizando o Ajax para poder fazer upload de um arquivo ZIP.

Quando faço os testes na minha máquina localmente, o upload ocorre normalmente. Porém quando faço isso em produção, se o arquivo for grande, um erro é gerado no Google Chrome.

```
net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

O estranho disso tudo é que não obtenho do servidor nenhuma resposta, a não ser o valor `(failed)` na aba "Network" do Console do Chrome.

Os dois testes que fiz, quando a requisição chegou a mais ou menos 2 minutos, esse erro ocorre, sem obter nenhuma resposta do servidor - pois todos os erros http que ocorrem no servidor, são gravados num log, porém nada foi relatado lá.

Esse erro seria alguma coisa referente ao Google Chrome?

**Observação**: Estou utilizado o Servidor IIS 10 e minha aplicação é Web Forms.

Comment: **Adicional**: Li algo na internet sobre os antivírus bloquearam a requisição e causar esse erro, porém não estou utilizando Antivírus.